# Target an element by it's last two characters

Tags: jquery, element

I have the following HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
     <div id="a_12"></div>
     <div id="a_13"></div>
     <div id="a_14"></div>
     <div id="a_15"></div>
     <div id="a_16"></div>
     <div id="a_17"></div>
</div>
```

How can I select the div that ends with 15 using jQuery?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the attribute-ends-with selector:

```
$('div[id$="15"]');
```

```js
$('div[id$="15"]').css('color', '#f90');
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto 0.5em auto;
}
div[id]::before {
  content: attr(id);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="a_12"></div>
  <div id="a_13"></div>
  <div id="a_14"></div>
  <div id="a_15"></div>
  <div id="a_16"></div>
  <div id="a_17"></div>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/g26HK/).

Or, you could use `filter()`:

```
$('div').filter(function(){
    return this.id.slice(-2) == '15';
});
```

```js
$('div').filter(function() {
  return this.id.slice(-2) == '15';
}).css('color', '#f90');
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto 0.5em auto;
}
div[id]::before {
  content: attr(id);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="a_12"></div>
  <div id="a_13"></div>
  <div id="a_14"></div>
  <div id="a_15"></div>
  <div id="a_16"></div>
  <div id="a_17"></div>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/g26HK/1/).

Or, with plain JavaScript:

```
document.querySelector('div[id$="15"]').style.color = '#f90';
```

```js
document.querySelector('div[id$="15"]').style.color = '#f90';
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto 0.5em auto;
}
div[id]::before {
  content: attr(id);
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="a_12"></div>
  <div id="a_13"></div>
  <div id="a_14"></div>
  <div id="a_15"></div>
  <div id="a_16"></div>
  <div id="a_17"></div>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/g26HK/2/).

Or even with just CSS:

```
div[id$="15"] {
  color: #f90;
}
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto 0.5em auto;
}
div[id]::before {
  content: attr(id);
}

div[id$="15"] {
  color: #f90;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="a_12"></div>
  <div id="a_13"></div>
  <div id="a_14"></div>
  <div id="a_15"></div>
  <div id="a_16"></div>
  <div id="a_17"></div>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/g26HK/3/).

References:

- CSS:

  - [Attribute selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-selectors).
- JavaScript:

  - [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).
- jQuery:
- [Attribute-ends-with (`[attribute$="value"]`) selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with/).
- [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).

Answer (score 2):

Try using [ends with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) on attribute value:

```
$('#wrapper').find('[id$="15"]'); //here find on the wrapper since you never know you may have some other element with id ends with 15 on your page.
```

When using ends with selector, you must be careful, so provide as much specificity as possible to end up selecting the right one.

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4jfas/)**